# How to convert Big Endian Hex to ASCII in Node?

Tags: node.js, network-programming, udp, hex, ascii

I'm trying to interpret a HEX message that is transmitted in network byte order (big endian), how should I proceed to achieve conversion to ASCII?

```
server.on('message', function (message, remote) {

//I receive message via UDP in HEX.

});
```

The message comes in this format:

```
2B 41 43 4B 19 EF 24 10 01 02 03 02 56 50 22 00 0A 02 3B 01 00 00 4E 07 DD 02 17 11 21 20 46 AD 4E 1E 0D 0A
```

With that being said, each byte has a parameter attached, let's say I have 4 bytes to parameter1, 2 bytes to parameter2 and 8 bytes to parameter 3, how would I interpret it?